# Почему не открывается ссылка в webview?

Tags: java, android, android-webview

В приложении есть две кнопки при нажатии на которые открываются две разных ссылки. Одна ссылка на страницу входа открывается нормально а реферальная ссылка не хочет открывается и выдает ошибку которая на скриншоте.
[image: не открывает ссылку]

Answer (score 0):

Добавил в свой applicationтег следующую строку :

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Решение:

Добавьте в свой applicationтег следующую строку :

android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
Как показано ниже:

```
<application
    ....
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    ....>
```